# Value of local variable is not used error

Tags: java, windows, cmd

```
try {
    String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "cmd /c start C:\\Users\\(username)\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\jai.bat"
    );
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error is in

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

The error is:

> the value of the local variable username is not used

I'm really new to this, i don't know what is wrong, any ideas?

Comment: I think it is suggestion, it is not error.

Comment: What exatly is unclear in this plain english sentence? You have a variable and don't use it, so what's the point of this variable?

Comment: simply remove it as it is not used and your "problem" would be solved

Comment: You should be using `"cmd /c start C:\\Users\\" + username + "...";` Instead of `"...\\(username)\\...";`

Comment: Thanks Frakcool, that solved it :)

Comment: To the others, I wasn't confused at what it was saying, I was confused as how it wasn't realising that the (username) wasnt there, but turns out I was using a completely wrong code :P

Comment: *"I was confused as how it wasn't realising that the (username) wasnt there"*: And why haven't you told us about that? Such informations are important for understand your question.

Comment: chill man lol no need to be so hostile

Comment: Note that it is better to use `user.home` instead of prepending `user.name` with `C:\\Users\\`, in case the user's home directory isn't on the C: drive etc.

Comment: Please see my answer @Jai it gives some more useful recommendations

Comment: And btw add (@ Username) (w/o the space between `@` and Username, to notify someone you've replied to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this `(username)`, with the real name of your account windows, so for example my account name is `YCF_L` so this should be like so :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
"cmd /c start C:\\Users\\YCF_L\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\jai.bat");
```

To check what is the real name open your computer and type `C:\Users`

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to make it dynamically then you should to concatenate your username like this :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "cmd /c start C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\jai.bat");
```

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying to make it so if I were to give this program to someone else, they can use it without changing that

Comment: ok @Jai i edit my answer check it now

Comment: Thanks man, will accept answer when it lets me :P

Comment: you are welcome @Jai ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the variable `username`, and you're trying to access user's directories the wrong way:

```
"cmd /c start C:\\Users\\(username)\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\jai.bat"
```

Will be translated to:

```
C:/Users/(username)/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/jai.bat
```

So, I suggest you to change it as:

```
"cmd /c start C:\\Users\\" + username + "AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\jai.bat"
```

And also to use a [`File#separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) like:

```
"cmd /c start C:" + File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + username + "...";
```

That way you don't have to escape `\`

Or way better:

```
String path = "cmd /c " + System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "AppData" + File.separator + "Roaming" + File.separator + ".minecraft" + File.separator + "jai.bat";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
```

Comment: There's very little point in using `File.separator` in a command that can only be run on Windows. It just harms readability.

Comment: @AndyTurner Somewhat agree, but it has helped me before when I missed a `\ ` and took me some time to see where the error was, that's why I'm suggesting it, however I still left the original String with the variable added. I like the `File.separator` version the most but a matter of taste